# QML-How-to Anonymously Access To TableView From Within Delegates?

Tags: qml

Using QML, I’m writing a custom itemDelegate and rowDelegate that I want to be able to use across any number of different TableView instances. As the code to follows shows, I’ve been able to accomplish this—but only in a way that I’m extremely dubious about it working in future (or previous, for that matter) releases of Qt. I’m currently using Qt 5.2.

```
Component {
    id: tableRowDelegate

     Rectangle {
     height: 16
     color: styleData.selected ? "#448" : (styleData.alternate? "#eee" : "#fff")

     property TableView tableView

     // The view is 8 levels up for the rowDelegate
     Component.onCompleted: {
          if (styleData.row > -1)  // Not entirely sure why this is needed -- worse, I don't know why it works; it just does
                tableView = parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent
      }

 // Other delegate code omitted for brevity
    }
}

Component {

id: tableCellDelegate

Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    color: "transparent"
    border.color: "#a3b3b3"
    border.width: 1
    radius: 5

    property TableView tableView

    // The View is 9 levels up for the itemDelegate
    Component.onCompleted: {
        tableView = parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent
    }

 // Other delegate code omitted for brevity
}
```

}

Once these delegates are constructed, access to the enclosing TableView is trivial
(and anonymous) by prefixing the property or signal name with ‘tableView.’; i.e.

```
tableView.alternatingRowColors
```

. . . just for example.

Is there really no better way to access the view from within a delegate without
hard-coding the ancestry, as in the above examples, or worse: without hard-binding
explicitly to the id of the TableView?

Caveat: I haven't *actually* tested this to make sure it'll work with a 2nd TableView.
It does work with the one I'm testing with.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Wayne

---

UPDATE with the answer.  Thanks again, mlvljr, for helping me brainstorm this through.

Inline, at the TableView level, I can use a Loader element as kind of a wrapper delegate to create the loose-binding with the "real" delegate; as follows:

```
rowDelegate : Loader {
    property TableView tableView        : itemsAcquiredList
    property QtObject  styleDataExported: styleData
    sourceComponent: tableRowDelegate
}
```

Those properties defined in the Loader are then available to
my "real" delegate.  I can copy-paste just that block into any other 
TableView, change just the id assigned to the tableView property, and
then use it with my reusable delegate.

It turns out that when I use a loader to get my delegate, styleData, and
model are no longer available directly in the loaded delegate; hence the
need for the 'styleDataExported' property in the Loader (the tableView
property now provides access to the model).  So, for extra sugar-coating,
I can add two property bindings inside the loaded delegate, as follows:

```
property QtObject  styleData: styleDataExported
property var       model    : tableView.model
```

And viola!  Now my delegate's code looks just like a real one, and I
can get all the properties, signals, and methods from the TableView
ancestor without ever using its 'id', and without ever making any 
assumptions about the internal ancestry of a delegate.

I don't know much about the loader, or whether I'll incur a performance
penalty for doing this, but it does give me a clean separation and
loose-binding between the view and the delegate.  For now, this is
exactly what I was looking for.

Update II: I have tested this with both an itemDelegate, and a rowDelegate,
and they both work as expected.

Comment: Seems, TableView uses a ListView internally for delegate instantiation (that's why the docs keep mentioning ListView's attached properties), hence, you may shorten the parent chain to smth like `ListView.view.parent` (totally not guaranteed to be portable, but there may be no other way, although -- a disclaimer -- I've never used the class, only looked at the docs and the source).

Comment: mlvir, that would have been a lot cleaner way, but unfortunately it doesn't work for TableView (at least, it didn't work for me).  I got a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null" when I tried :(

Comment: From what I can make out, ListView isn't an attached property of TableView; it's actually in the ancestral chain -- parent.parent.parent.parent -- about 4 levels up from the rowDelegate, but still not a direct child of the view.

Comment: Crap, let me fire up this in Creator and see for myself, hold on!

Comment: Ok, so the ListView they use has something composed of nested Loaders, with the innermost actually instantiating the `itemDelegate`, and `ListView.xxx` attached properties have meaning only within the top-level delegate -- hence the error. Seems no other chance to cope with this sanely other than by accessing the view via an id (and if you want to mix and match your views and delegates, you can add a property like "Item tableView" to the delegates, and set it up from an id when used within each view).

Comment: Eureka! I have found it!  mlvljr, I'm not entirely sure if it's what you had in mind, but it works for a rowDelegate, and I expect it will for other delegates too.  I'll update my original question with the answer I have found.

Comment: Yes, and if you decide to omit Loader, no forwarding will be even necessary, as described at: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22937 :)

Comment: That's a very interesting thread.  It explains a lot.  I don't, however, think it's possible to side-step the loader.  The workhorse logic of my delegate is defined as a component specifically so I can reuse it with other views.  If I don't call the loader explicitly, we've already seen that QML calls it implicitly; presumably *because* it's defined as a component.  Not really sure about that, but now that I understand what's going on (at least superficially) I'm really quite ok with the approach we worked out here. :)

Comment: Well, each .qml defined a component, yes, instantiated implicitly by the engine, and you can choose specific components (referencing inline ones by `id`, and those in source files by URLs) with Loader. I.e. you could still have a perfectly reusable component if it was just a plain Item in a .qml file, but the way with Component works too, of course. G'luck with them QMLs :)

Comment: If you've solved this, can you self-answer so we know it's solved?